# How to wrap Ruby strings in HTML tags

Tags: html, ruby

I'm looking for help on two things.  1) I'm looking for a way for Ruby to wrap strings in HTML.  I have a program I'm writing that generates a Hash of word frequencies for a text file and I want to take the results and place it into an HTML file rather than print to STDOUT.  I'm thinking each string needs to be wrapped in an HTML paragraph tag using readlines() or something, but I can't quite figure it out.  Then, once I've wrapped the strings in HTML 2) I want to write to an empty HTML file.

Right now my program looks like:

```
filename = File.new(ARGV[0]).read().downcase().scan(/[\w']+/)
frequency = Hash.new(0)
words.each { |word| frequency[word] +=1 }
frequency.sort_by { |x,y| y }.reverse().each{ |w,f| puts "#{f}, #{w}" }
```

So if we ran a text file through this and received:

```
35, the
27, of
20, to
16, in
# . . .
```

I'd want to export to an HTML file that wraps the lines like:

```
<p>35, the</p>
<p>27, of</p>
<p>20, to</p>
<p>16, in</p>
# . . .
```

Thanks for any tips in advance!

Comment: You really don't need the parentheses after no-arg method invocations...

Comment: @Jacob I know, I keep going back and forth between including them and removing them. In some ways I like having them there for readability's sake (e.g., I can see immediately what are methods and what are variables) but also worry it clutters up the program.

Comment: Typically, when outputting any sort of frequency-counts, you'll encounter cases where the count is the same for multiple elements. For words with the same count, what do you want to do? Display them in whatever order they appear, or sort them in ascending or descending order?

Comment: Since you can't call variables, that should be obvious.

Comment: @Jörg True. I'm still new to Ruby so I'm working out best practices, etc, yet.  It's my understanding that there is no accepted Ruby standard for handling this. Do most Ruby programmers leave out parens?

@Tin Man At the moment I just have things displayed in order of their number frequency -- I haven't yet figured out how to order first by number, then by letter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a trivial problem.

```
#open file, write, and close

File.open('words.html', 'w') do |ostream|
  words = File.new(ARGV[0]).read.downcase.scan(/[\w']+/)
  frequency = Hash.new
  words.each { |word| frequency[word] +=1 }

  frequency.sort_by {|x, y| y }.reverse.each do |w,f| 
     ostream.write "<p>#{f}, #{w}</p>" 
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2):

Something like this:

```
File.open("output.html", "w") do |output|

  words = File.new(ARGV[0]).read().downcase().scan(/[\w']+/)
  frequency = Hash.new(0)
  words.each { |word| frequency[word] +=1 }
  frequency.sort_by { |x,y| y }.reverse().each do |w,f| 
   output.write "<p>#{f}, #{w}</p>\n"
  end

end
```

Answer (score 1):

You may want to look into the [dom gem](https://rubygems.org/gems/dom) that I have developed. Your string can be generated like this:

```
require "dom"

frequency.sort_by(&:last).reverse.map{|w, f| "#{f}, #{w}".dom(:p)}.dom
# => "<p>35, the</p><p>27, of</p><p>20, to</p><p>16, in</p>"
```